# Is there a difference between them, if have,what's it?

Tags: php

```
$a = true;

1，new test($a);

2，new test(true);
```

Is there a difference between them(1,2), if have,what's of it? thank you,.

Answer (score 4):

Well the other one uses a variable and the other one doesn't. This causes a fatal error in this case:

```
class test {

    public function __construct( &$a )
    {

    }
}

$a = true;

new test($a);

new test(true); //Fatal error because this cannot be passed by reference
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, it depends on how test is defined.

If `test` is defined such that input parameters are [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), then `2` would raise a fatal error, since `true` is a literal value.

Also, `test` could have side effects that mean that the order in which you execute lines `1` and `2` matter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the constructor of the `test` class. In a regular **pass-by-value** constructor they are exactly the same:

```
class test {
  public $b;
  function __construct($a) { $this->b = $a; }
}
```

Here, `$obj->b` will be `true` for both your statements, as expected.

If, on the other hand, you are [**passing by reference**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) you may get different results if you change the global `$a` later on. Example:

```
class test {
  public $b;
  function __construct( &$a ) { $this->b = &$a; }
}

$a = true;
$obj = new test($a);
$a = false;
```

`$obj->b` will be `false` in this case because it is a reference to `$a`! With references, you can also do it the other way around, changing `$a` from within the constructor:

```
class test {
  function __construct( &$a ) { $a = false; }
}

$a = true;
$obj = new test($a);
```

`$a` will now be false even in the global scope!

In addition, `new test(true)` is not possible to do when passing by reference because you cannot have a reference to a literal value, only to other variables.

Comment: SiGanteng, I agree. Would be nice with an explanation.